# Is there a way to unit test an innaccessible callback function that is called from a child React component using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am unit testing a React 16 functional component that defines a callback and passes it as a property down to the next component to be invoked when a click event fires.

```
import React from 'react'

function OuterComponent() {

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    openDialog() // <--- This code is inaccessible from my "OuterComponent.test.js" unit test 
  }

  return <MyDialog clickHandler={handleClick} />
}
export default OuterComponent
```

I am seeking 100% test coverage and would like to mock all other components/functions using jest that are not part of the "OuterComponent" component.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to mock the **MyDialog** component in order to have it trigger the **handleClick** function.

I also tried to mock the component using this snippet but it still seems to try to load all the imports from **MyDialog**

```
jest.doMock('components/MyDialog', () => {
    return () => () => <div />
})
//... other mocks along with **openDialog**

//...and in my describe/it...
MyDialog.mockImplementation(() => {})

OuterComponent().handleClick()
expect(openDialog).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

The hope here was that I could render an empty div for **MyDialog** and just simply call the **handleClick** function to test it.  Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong or have any other ideas of how to test it?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not test that `handleClick` has been called, rather than `openDialog`?
If what you want to test is that `openDialog` did what it was supposed to do (ie opening a dialog), why not simply test the (mocked) dialog is present rather than checking that the function has been called? Ie. don't be so preoccupied with implementations details and just test what the user would see.

Comment: @NicolasSEPTIER This would work for me as well, but I've not yet figured out a way to mock the dialog and call its `clickHandler` property function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can mock a var in a closure. The best you can do is something along those lines:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from 'react-testing-library';

jest.mock(
  'components/MyDialog',
  () => ({ clickHandler }) => (
    <button
      onClick={clickHandler}
      test-id="button"
    >
      Click me
    </button>
  ),
);

it('should call clickHandler', () => {
  const onClick = jest.fn(() => null);
  const { queryByTestId } = render(<MyDialog clickHandler={onClick} />);
  fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('button'));
  expect(onClick.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
});
```

You actually test the ability for you `MyDialog` to render something that can execute a callback.

Comment: In my case the `onClick` function that you have mocked is defined as a callback function (handleClick) in the parent Component (OuterComponent) and that is the code I want to test.

Comment: Well then, you can't test a function defined in a functional component.